# Which programme calls csh.cshrc?

Tags: aix, csh

I understand that when a user logs into unix remotely, first a getty process is started. If authentication is successful, then etc/environement is called. However, I do not understand when is csh.cshrc and csh.login is called during this process?

Answer (score 1):

`csh.cshrc` and `csh.login` are global versions of the `~/.cshrc` and `~/.login` (or `~/.csh_login`), e.g. csh's configuration files. When csh is executed it reads both `/etc/csh.cshrc` and `~/.cshrc` (it also reads both cshlogin-files).  When user doesn't have `~/.cshrc` in his/her home directory, csh can only read `/etc/csh.cshrc`. That is the case because then the root (or someone with e.g. correct sudo rights) can set `/etc/csh.cshrc` to contain the basic settings and every user can customise his/her own settings in `~/.cshrc`.

Comment: IIRC they are read even if the user has a version.

Comment: I understand the csh read both /etc/csh.cshrc and /etc/csh.login. But when is csh executed? Assuming a user logs in, which programme executes csh? Does /etc/passwd call csh?

Comment: csh is executed by `login` (which prompts you for the username and password).

Answer (score 1):

From `man csh`:

```
  An instance of csh begins by executing commands from the file
 /etc/csh.cshrc and, if this is a login shell, /etc/csh.login.  It then
 executes commands from .cshrc in the home directory of the invoker, and,
 if this is a login shell, the file .login in the same location.  It is
 typical for users on CRTs to put the command stty crt in their .login
 file, and to also invoke tset(1) there.
```